# How do I use alternate versions of the WebView2 runtime?

Tags: c++, win32gui, webview2

This seems like a very stupid (basic) question.

I am writing a C++ graphical (Windows) application that uses the new WebView2 control. The samples provided by Microsoft are quite nice. But I am having trouble with things that aren't shown in the samples. But after two days of googling and searching other ways, I can't find an answer. I'm hoping this community can help.

I'm trying to call the WebView2_4 method add_DownloadStarting(), but trying to get the WebView2_4 pointer from the WebView2 window keeps giving me an E_NOINTERFACE.

In particular, I have the following code:

```
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2> wvWnd = nullptr;
    if (controller != nullptr) {
        pWebView2->m_webviewController = controller;
        pWebView2->m_webviewController->get_CoreWebView2(&wvWnd);
    }
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_4> wvWnd4 = wvWnd.try_query<ICoreWebView2_4>();
```

That last line results in wvWnd4 having a NULL m_ptr. Stepping into that last line gets to a call to QueryInterface(), which returns the hr value E_NOINTERFACE.

Note that a call like

```
    wil::com_ptr<ICoreWebView2_3> wvWnd3 = wvWnd.try_query<ICoreWebView2_3>();
```

results in wvWnd3 have a valid m_ptr (not NULL).

I suspect this is due to the fact that I am using the current WebView2 runtime (version 1.0.864.35), and I need to use a later version (1.0.902-prerelease). I have downloaded and installed (using nuget) the prerelease version, but I don't know how to actually get it to load. The Output window when running my application in the Visual Studio 2017 debugger shows:

```
'myapp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\src\c\myapp\Debug\Win32\bin\WebView2Loader.dll'.
'myapp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\EdgeWebView\Application\91.0.864.59\EBWebView\x86\EmbeddedBrowserWebView.dll'.
```

which is the old version.

Or maybe there is some other issue? I'm starting to get frustrated, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you use a `preview` version of `WebView2` you must install a Canary build of Microsoft Edge - that is used by preview WebView2.  You can download it here: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/canary

Comment: @PoulBak - thanks for the info. And while that may be part of the solution, it is not the complete solution. I downloaded the Canary build, but my application is still using the originally-installed version (same dll is being loaded, and the wvWnd4 pointer is still NULL. Is there something I need to do with CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions with either the browserExecuteFolder, or the environmentOptions arguments?

Comment: Forget my comment, I think this what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#fixed-version-distribution-mode

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am also stuck in same thing.

Comment: I did not figure it out, sadly. I decided to wait until a later version was not a preview release and then test that new release. But then I got distracted by other things and haven't been able to return to this, yet. Sorry.